# Capture ip address of machine of the user

Tags: php, ip

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['action']) && ($_GET['action'] == 'submit')) {
    $name    = $_POST['name'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $email   = $_POST['email'];

    $ip        = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    $messageip = "User IP: $ip\n\n" . $messageip;

    $sql   = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE email = '" . $email . "'";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if ($count >= 1) {

        echo "User Already in Exists<br/>";
    } else {

        $newUser = "INSERT INTO tbl_user(name,message,email,ip_address) values('$name','$message','$email','$messageip')";
        $query2  = mysql_query($newUser);

        if ($query2) {
            echo "You are now registered<br/>";
        } else {
            echo "Error adding user in database<br/>";
        }
    }
    echo $name . '<br/>';
    echo $message . '<br/>';
    echo $email . '<br/>';
    echo $messageip . '<br/>';
}
?>
```

I am using this code to capture the ip address but i cannot get the machine ip of the particular user from which i can display the address by dynamically, so can anyone help me out on this topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be concatenating a wrong (empty) var.

Try changing this:

> $messageip = "User IP: $ip\n\n" . $messageip;

to this:

> $messageip = "User IP: $ip\n\n" . $ip;

Comment: Thank you! its working... and one more think "If a user is working under as router then will the it capture machine ip or router ip??"

Comment: The router IP obviously, because that is his IP on the "outer" network, i.e. the Internet. His IP address behind the router (NAT) is in fact his local IP from a different scope (192.168....) and it would make no sense to retreive this IP address. For a basic introduction you can check [this link](http://compnetworking.about.com/od/routers/), and for a more detailed explanation you can check the [NAT wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation)